# Meaning of colon in Bash after a double pipe

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand this piece of code:

```
. functions.sh || { : ; echo "Error while loading the specified file" >&2; exit 2; }
```

I get that the code in the bracket is called when the specified file isn't available. But what does this `: ;` mean?
Moreover, when you delete it, then the script doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [colon is  null statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_003a), so it does nothing. The semi-colon [ends a list of commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists).

Not sure why anyone would write the above, it's basically "do nothing, then do the `echo`" which seems like it could be simplified. Could be somebody's copy-paste baggage.

Comment: But if you write this: `. functions.sh || {echo "Error while loading the specified file" >&2; exit 2; }` then it doesn't work - the exit command somehow requires it I guess.

Comment: Nevermind .. I forgot to add a space after the { symbol. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `do_something || :` is an idiom meaning to ignore the failure of `do_something` which would end the entire script if `set -e` AKA `set -o errexit` was enabled.

Comment: To add to Martin's comment, someone else probably didn't understand the `cmd || :` idiom, and rather than replace `:` with the log message, kept it inside a new command group.

Comment: Autoconf uses : all over the place to reset the $? status which some shells screw up after an if block... Not to be recommended generally. (We still support the dreaded Solaris /bin/sh though!)

Comment: @MartinVidner: If you make your comment an answer I will upvote it